# Average of one measure for several variables

Tags: r

I have measures of variables that have different features in my R dataframe
Here is a sample dataset :

[image]

Basically, every word has its own measure and can have any pos, session and author. I would like to have a way to create a new dataset with the mean measure for each set of variable/features. So an average of  the speeds everytime cat has the features :author 1 session 2 and pos noun. Then the average for the same combination but session 3 and so on and so forth...

How would one go about doing that ?

Comment: `library(data.table);  setDT(df)[, mean(measure), by = .(word, pos, session, author) ]`

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `tidyverse` approach.

```
require(tidyverse) 
#Creating sample data. 
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(measure = round(rnorm(10, mean = 200, sd = 20)), 
                 #Creating random "words" (it can be done nicer than this)
                 word = rep(c("Cat", "began", "Aggressive")), 
                 pos = rep(c("noun", "verb", "Adjective")), 
                 session = rep(sample(c(1,2,3)),10), 
                 author = rep(sample(c(1,2,3)),10))

#Now we need to group_by() and calculate the mean for each measure by word, pos, session, author
#If I understood correctly the order you want

MyMean <- df %>% 
  group_by(word, pos, session, author) %>% 
  #I use na.rm = TRUE in case you have missing values. 
  summarise(M = mean(measure, na.rm = TRUE))

MyMean
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R this could be done several ways. The `tapply method would return an array that could be accessed with elements of its margins:

```
meas_tbl <- with(dfrm, 
                tapply( measure, 
                     INDEX = list(word, pos, session, author), 
                     FUN= mean, na.rm=TRUE ) )

 meas_tbl[ "cat", "noun", "2", "1" ]
```

If you omit a value from an array index position you get all possible sub-arrays (slices)